# Converting a breadboard to a schematic

Tags: arduino, breadboard

[image]

I am familiar with converting schematics to breadboards, but how would I go about converting this breadboard to a schematic?

Comment: Do you have the schematic for the Arduino board to start from?

Answer (score 4):

You can follow these steps:

1. Decide whether you want to create a schematic on paper or an EDA
   software. This is entirely up to you. If you want to go for a
   software, EasyEDA and CircuitLab are good options to start on.
2. Identify each component in your breadboard circuit and what its
   symbol in a schematic would be. You can easily find symbols for
   different components on internet.
3. Draw a main component first i.e. arduino uno in this case. You can
   make a simple block with the exact pinout to represent it.
4. Draw other components one by one and wire them according to your breadboard
   circuit. Make sure to write parameters (part number/identifier/value) of each
   component with it.
5. Connecting ground and Vcc for each component can sometimes make a
   mess and difficult to read the diagram, use power terminal symbols
   in that case to keep the schematic as clean as possible.

I would recommend starting on a software as you can easily modify and edit the schematic if needed. You can also print it on a paper if you have access to a printer.

Answer (score 1):

This one doesn't look too complex, but a generic method is to consider a schema in terms of components (devices with at least two terminals) and a list of nodes (connections between terminals).

This is how circuits are modeled internally in PCB layout packages anyhow. The schematic representation defines the components and netlist, which is exported to a separate program which models the physical characteristics of the components and allows you to create the copper which is the nodes. So what you are doing is the reverse.

For a simple situation, you can often go straight from circuit to schema, but when things get more complex a more rigorous approach is useful.

An example:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmq9zY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This circuit has four components, each with two terminals, and three nodes. The nodes are as follows:

- A: V1 +, R1 top, C1 top
- B: R1 bottom, L1 top
- C: V1 -, L1 bottom, C1 bottom

If you find yourself needing to reverse engineer a complex circuit, you can adopt this general approach:

1. take a picture or make a diagram of the physical locations of the components
2. label each component and its terminals
3. create a node list by inspection or using a multimeter on the physical device
4. create a nice looking schematic from the node list

This generic approach can be used to generate a schematic of even quite complex circuits.

Answer (score 1):

Decide whether you want to treat the Arduino as an external thing, or as a "blob" on your diagram.  If it's the former, create connectors on your diagram, and label them to match the labels on the Arduino.  If it's the latter, draw it in the same way as for an integrated circuit.

There's a very strong convention in circuit diagrams that the highest voltages are at the top of the diagram, and the lowest voltages are at the bottom.  As a starting point, it's often easiest to draw a horiontal line near the top of the page for the positive (3.3V in your case) and another near the bottom for the negative (GND).

There's also a very strong convention that signals come in on the left, travel left to right, with the outputs on the right.  So if you're drawing it with connections from the Arduino, draw the inputs fron the Arduino on the left, and the signals out to the Arduino on the right.

Once you have the right framework, draw the components in between to join everything up.

Answer (score 0):

This is a picture of **Tinkercad** (as was pointed out to me in the comments, Thanks!). There is an option to directly show a schematic: [Tinkercad schematic view](https://www.tinkercad.com/#schematic_view).
A nice example of a complete workflow is here: [Example for Tinkercad](https://www.tinkercad.com/blog/send-to-fusion-for-electronics)

In a similar software like [**Fritzing**](https://fritzing.org/). There is also a schematic view to show the circuit diagram. It is not directly referenced in the example but the button is visible in the screenshots:
[Example with Fritzing](https://fritzing.org/learning/tutorials/designing-pcb/)

Edit: Added description for Tinkercad, and adapted reference for Fritzing.

Comment: A layout is not a schematic either, though. So how does this answer the question?

Comment: Arduino Uno in Fritzing doesn't have a cable. Looks like it's made in TinkerCAD instead.

Comment: @PCBCrewEngineer: Good catch, I will adapt my answer.

Comment: @Ludin Yes, you are right. I was thinking one step ahead without it was mentioning in the question. I will edit.